# Event record AccountId field returning as Null

Tags: apex, soql, account, event

I have created a Event record under an Account as shown in below screenshot but when i try to fetch the accountId field through SOQL it returns as null though there is a value in the AccountId field.

```
Select Subject,AccountId,WhatId,WhoId,Who.Name,What.Name from Event where Id='00U0v0000016C0Y'
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm):

> Represents the ID of the related Account. The AccountId is determined
> as follows. If the value of WhatId is any of the following objects,
> then Salesforce uses that object’s AccountId.
>
> Account Opportunity Contract Custom object that is a child of Account
> If the value of the WhatId field is any other object, and the value of
> the WhoId field is a Contact object, then Salesforce uses that
> contact’s AccountId. (If your organization uses Shared Activities,
> Salesforce uses the AccountId of the primary contact.)
>
> Otherwise, Salesforce sets the value of the AccountId field to null.

Can you check values of the following fields for current event : WhatId and WhoId ?
What is an API name of field labeled "Account" ?

Comment: The value of WhoId and WhatId are null.The API name of the field Account is AccountId which is also null.

Comment: populate WhatId  with desired id of Account and field AccountId  will be populated as you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you create any event for `Account`, by default Salesforce stores `AccountId` in event fields of `AccountId` and `WhatId`.

I think you're not querying correct `eventId`. I tried sample creating sample event of my developer org and it works as expected. I've highlighted `WhatId` and `AccountId`. If you observe closely, they're same. Refer below snapshot:
[image]